# How can I check if a list index exists?

Tags: python, list

Seems as though

```
if not mylist[1]:
    return False
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: `mylist[1]` will return the element at index 1. Say that this element is the value `False`, how would you consider it?

Comment: Yeah, my code is dreadful. What I tried to do seems like a very unpythonic way of doing it if it worked.

Comment: Where do you get the value `1` from?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You just have to check if the index you want is in the range of `0` and the length of the list, like this

```
if 0 <= index < len(list):
```

it is actually internally evaluated as

```
if (0 <= index) and (index < len(list)):
```

So, that condition checks if the index is within the range [0, length of list).

**Note:** Python supports negative indexing. Quoting Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations),

> If `i` or `j` is negative, the index is relative to the end of the string: `len(s) + i` or `len(s) + j` is substituted. But note that -0 is still 0.

It means that whenever you use negative indexing, the value will be added to the length of the list and the result will be used. So, `list[-1]` would be giving you the element `list[-1 + len(list)]`.

So, if you want to allow negative indexes, then you can simply check if the index doesn't exceed the length of the list, like this

```
if index < len(list):
```

---

Another way to do this is, excepting `IndexError`, like this

```
a = []
try:
    a[0]
except IndexError:
    return False
return True
```

When you are trying to access an element at an invalid index, an `IndexError` is raised. So, this method works.

---

**Note:** The method you mentioned in the question has a problem.

```
if not mylist[1]:
```

Lets say `1` is a valid index for `mylist`, and if it returns a [Falsy value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). Then `not` will negate it so the `if` condition would be evaluated to be Truthy. So, it will return `False`, even though an element actually present in the list.

Comment: If the negative index is too low you will get an `IndexError` for being out of range, so you might want to check `index >= -len(list)` if you are supporting that.

Comment: Another drawback to the first method is that Python allows non sequential indexes via .insert

Comment: @BrettG actually it doesn't. While you will not get an error if you do `lst.insert(3, 'c')` on an empty list, the value `'c'` will be inserted at the next available slot (in this case index 0). At least for Python 3

Comment: Here is a crazy thought: What if [-x] where x can be -1, -2 etc.?

Answer (score 16):

In the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) style of Python:

```
try:
    mylist[1]
except IndexError:
    print "Index doesn't exist!"
```

Comment: I personally can't wrap my head around accepting that the only solution to "check" the validity of the indices is to throw an error and trigger a whole bunch of hiccups. (ie. I am skeptical about the performance implications of this method)

Answer (score 9):

In the case of integer-indexed lists, I'd simply do

```
if 1 < len(mylist):
  ...
```

For dicts, you can of course do

```
if key in mydict:
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative (but somewhat slower) way of doing it:

```
if index not in range(len(myList)):
    return False
```

It gets a bit more verbose when accounting for negative indices:

```
if index not in range(-len(myList), len(myList)):
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
assert len(mylist) >= abs(index) + int(index >= 0), "Index out of range"
```

or

```
assert len(mylist) > abs(index) - int(index < 0), "Index out of range"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do:

```
if index in dict(enumerate(mylist)):
    return True
```

Although is will probably be even less efficient than `range(len(mylist))`. Maybe someone should propose a keys() method for lists that returns the range of the keys in PEP.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach returns the `True` result for `index == 0` and for negative index values (if such an index is valid for the list, for example `listIn[-2]` for `[0, 1, 2]`):

```
def isInListRange(listIn, index):
  """ Description: Function to detect if list index out of range
    Import: from shared.isInListRange import isInListRange
    Test: python -m shared.isInListRange
  """

  try:
    return True if (index == 0 and len(listIn) > 0) or listIn[index] else False
  except:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

First, consider the boundary conditions.

1. The largest valid index into a list of length `l` is `l-1`; beginning at 0, this defines `l` elements.
2. The smallest valid index into a list of `l` is `-l`; beginning at -1, this again defines `l` elements.

The resulting expression in the context of the original question:

```py
isValidIndex = lambda l, i: -len(l) <= i < len(l)

if not isValidIndex(myList, 1):
  return False
```

Note that there are *no* valid indexes into the empty array (length 0) and this property is held here - there is no `i` that satisfies `0 <= i < 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do the following:

```
# Allocate an array containing 5 elements.
items = range(5)
# Allocate a list of indices to test this code with.
indices_to_test = [-10, -2, -1, 0, 2, 5]
# Allocate a list of expected validity for each element in the above array.
expected_validity = [False, True, True, True, True, False]
# Generate a result array that returns a bool/True/False value for each index.
results = [abs(index) < len(items) for index in indices_to_test]
# Print the results. 
print(results)
# Expected output: [False, True, True, True, True, False]
assert results == expected_validity
```

TLDR; The above code basically boils down to the condition `abs(index) < len(items)`, which upholds a negative index to the same validity requirements for a positive index (be within the length of the array).

Realising that there are "special" cases in Python. So, I am more than happy to have someone point me in a better direction, however, been looking all over the place for a more efficient, easier way of doing the same and I have not been able to find anything better (without throwing an error and causing possible performance issues).